# Insert Contacts to a .csv file using terminal and shell script

Tags: shell, csv, terminal

Hi I want to make a script that inserts contacts to a `.csv` file. It asks the user to type First Name, Last Name, and Phone number and then the output will be saved in a file named `contacts.csv`.
For example : `John,Dawson,2102983187`

Tried this but want to separate output with commas as it's on the example and it has to be in a loop.

```
#!/bin/bash    
IFS=','          
touch contacts.csv   
echo "What's your contact's first name?"    
read fname     
echo "$fname" | grep '^[[:upper:]]\+[a-z]\{0,\}' >> contacts.csv      
echo "What's your contact's last name?"     
read lname   
echo "$lname" | grep '^[[:upper:]]\+[a-z]\{0,\}' >> contacts.csv   
echo "Whats your contact's phone number"    
read phone    
echo "$phone" | grep '[0-9]\{10\}$' >> contacts.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh

read fname?"What's your contact's first name? "
read lname?"What's your contact's last name? "
read phone?"What's your contact's phone number? "
[[ $fname =~ ^[[:upper:]][a-z]+$ ]] || { echo "$fname should be uppercase first char followed by lowercase chars" ; exit 1; }
[[ $lname =~ ^[[:upper:]][a-z]+$ ]] || { echo "$fname should be uppercase first char followed by lowercase chars" ; exit 2; }
[[ $phone =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]      || { echo "$fname should be digits only" ; exit 3; }

echo "$fname,$lname,$phone" >> contacts.csv
```

Changing IFS isn't necessary. IFS=*Input* separator, and from your checks, I assume, that you don't want `,` in your input.

Read can provide a prompt, no need to use echo.

I would check all inputs first, and then write to output.

If you put the block between

```
while true; do
  ...
done
```

An empty input will stop the processing